# Affine change of coordinates on linear function

Tags: linear-transformations

I am currently reading some books on finite Elements and I have a question regarding one step in the proof of one lemma:

> Let $P$ be a polynomial of degree $d \geq 1$ that vanishes on a hyperplane L, i.e. the hyperplane $\{x: L(x)=0\}$. Then we can write $P=LQ$, where $Q$ is a polynomial of degree  $(d-1)$.

Here L is a non-degenerate linear function. They proceed as follows:
Since affine transformations map polynomials of degree $d$ onto polynomials of degree $d$, make an affine change of coordinates such that:
$$ L(\hat{x},x_n)=x_n$$
and $L(\hat{x},x_n)=0$ is the $\hat{x}$-axis. Here $\hat{x}=(x_1,...,x_{n-1})$

The rest of the proof is pretty understandable and not hard to figure out yourself, however I have a hard time really understanding this affine transformation of $L$, since I have not really worked with it before. I really want to know how such transformation of a linear function $L$ is done especially in an easy way to understand. For example, in $\mathbb{R}$ for a linear function $f(x)=ax+b$, would the transformation: $$\hat{x}=(x-b)/a$$ be the correct transformation, such that $f(\hat{x})=x$ or am I wrong? If correct, the my question is how would such transformation look like in higher dimension?

Any suggestions, explanation or advices where I can find more information to understand it is greatly appreciated. The book is: The Mathematical Theory of Finite Element Methods" by S. Brenner and L. Scott.